# HTTP 404 error while trying to browse web site created on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I am completely newbie with IIS. I have Win2008 with IIS 7.5 installed. I can start "Default Web Site" via IIS Manager GUI , but I get "HTTP 404 error - webpage cannot be found" while trying to browse it. What webpage is expected ? I have index.htm & default.aspx under c:\inetpub\wwwroot ... Also , I am not sure where to look for the logs. What is the best way to troubleshoot? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are accessing you website through out the good port? Check in your IIS configuration for your default web site, maybe it is not set to port 80 (which should be the default).

Also, many other programs like Skype may use this port already and IIS is not able to activate the website because the port is already in use.

You should try to set the IIS default website port to something else than 80.

Give it a try!

Comment: the site starts ok , and I see

Comment: C:\inetpub\wwwroot>netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:88             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: However, I still get HTTP 404 error while trying to browse it

Comment: did you check in the IIS logs (inetpub/logs/logfiles) ? did the IIS welcome screen poped up f=with localhost:88?

Comment: no. I get the same error on both 80 and 88 ports. Site starts on both ports , I see 80/88 port listening on netstat output but I cannot browse it ( http 404 error - webpage cannot be found ). Also , I see NO logs under c:\inetpub\logs

Comment: I just added full access to my user for inetpub folder. still no logs. and no success to browse web site :((

Answer (score 0):

Check your default website mode, I guess its process was stopped. Try to restart the process. If you get any "Process is being used" error, try to close the exe's like skype of any third parties which refer the 80 port.